# Can't get attribute 'function_inner' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'E:\\python\\Test\\test.py'>

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python script in windows 10 which has running succeed in macOS.
Then it throws an exception. 
After running the following test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing


def function_def(*args, **kwargs):
    print('run success')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def function_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print('run success')
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_inner)
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

It throws following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'function_inner' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'E:\\python\\Test\\test.py'>
```

But, if use

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_def)
```

not for

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_inner)
```

then it run succeed

I'm using python 3.6.1, windows 10 x64, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

when the `multiprocessing` library copies your main module, it won't run it as the `__main__` script and therefore anything defined inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is not defined in the child process namespace. Hence, the `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1):

`function_inner` is only defined if you run your script as a main script.

`multiprocessing` will import your module in the new process and try to call your function, e.g.

```
import test
test.function_inner()
```

However, `if __name__ == '__main__'` will evaluate `False`, and `function_inner` will not be defined.

Comment: I use lambda function instead of function_inner [ such as multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda *args, **kwargs: print('run success')) ] has the same exception. Are they the same for the same reason?

Comment: I may understand, in Unix-like system, multiprocessing will call fork(), and fork() will copy of the parent's address space and give it to the child, but windows is different, is that right?

Comment: @bawuju Yes, on windows you need `if __name__ == '__main__'` otherwise the module will be re-executed and more processes started, ad-infinitum. See [Mulitprocessing: Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)